# Adjusting parent height containing absolute children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a form that has multiple pages that I would like to scroll in/out of view.  I have to use absolute positioning to force the divs (pages) to scroll in a single line; however, this causes the parent divs height to not be responsive to the children (which have varying heights based on amount of content plus dynamic content being added to them).

How can I make the parents height be responsive to the children while still allowing my pages to scroll in a single line (I have already tried float)?

Is there anyway to achieve the same effect as the jsFiddle Demo without having to use absolute positioning?

Example: [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FkNa2/228/)  <--- How do I make the toggle button remain below the divs no matter how tall they are?

```
#div1{
  width: 500px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#div2{
  width: 500px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

<p>some content here </p>
<div class="container">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>    
</div>
<button>Toggle</button>
```

## **EDIT**

Updated jsFiddle to show problem better.

Answer (score 0):

You inspect the height and position of the child elements and calculate the total height and apply that to the parent. Absolutely-positioned elements have their own layout context, so CSS alone cannot solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The height in #div1 and #div2 is causing an overflow of the .container div:

Set the height of #div1 and #div2 to the same height as its container:

```
#div1{
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#div2{
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Or set the .container to overflow:hidden:

```
.container {
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden
  height: 100px;
}
```

Updated jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/FkNa2/193/

Comment: I don't want the overflow to be hidden, I want the container to expand as the div gets validation errors appended to it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want, i Updated your fiddle:

1. Button position is fixed at document loading, based on height of the biggest absolute element:

   ```
    $(function(){   
     $('#container').height(Math.max($('#div1').height(),$('#div2').height()));
   });
   ```

you can see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FkNa2/189/)

1. Button position is recomputed each time the toggle is done, you can use the complete option of one of your toggle to handle it:

   ```
   $div2.toggle('slide', {
       direction: 'left', 
       complete:function(){
          $('#container').height($('#'+currentDiv).height());
       }
   }, 'slow');
   ```

see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FkNa2/190/)

Comment: This almost works, except when I try to validate the page before the toggle and I get validation messages added to the absolutely positioned div which would push the div over the toggle button.  Does that mean I need to calculate the height of each error message and add it to the parent container upon validation?

Comment: Not sure to understand, if your div is absolute positioned, it should ne be pushed down by the error message. Can you update the fiddle if not too complicated ?

Comment: I have updated the fiddle in the question with a span to simulate form validation.  Click the span about 6+ times to experience my problem.  I need the divs height to adjust as they are added, and they can be of any height and can change at any time.

Answer (score 0):

use min-height for #div2

```
    #div2{
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Close, but I also need the div to push things down as it gets bigger.

Comment: you wont be able to do that with #div2 and #div1 having position:absolute . you should take that out of the css, and try using jquery.animate (https://api.jquery.com/animate/) for the horizontal animations. i have a project due so i dont have time to make a jsfiddle, but hopefully that is a helpful pointer.

Comment: I tried using jquery animations, the problem is that is looks terrible because one div slides in below the other div and then moves up to fill the old divs spot.